# Is there a good business plan template?

Tags: templates

I'm looking for a good business plan LaTeX template for a web startup. In my opinion it shouldn't have a standing out "classic" look - for example, fonts like Caslon, Garamond or Computer Modern ooze too much authority for a small company in my eyes; however, I'm open to everything.

Any suggestions / pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: well, you can edit your question a bit to contain more details, and we could build something together based on KOMA or memoir class ...

Comment: Please provide more details, otherwise, we'll have to close this question.

Comment: @lockstep: sorry, didn't see the notification earlier. The problem is that I don't *know* what exactly constitues a good and tried business plan template regarding layout, fonts etc; I was hoping for a pointer like "this is regarded the standard template" or some links of templates made by people far more knowledgeable than me when it comes to typography and design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer this older question: No, there seems to be no business plan template in LaTeX available. There is [nothing on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=business+plan&search_type=description) and I only could find unsuccessful forum / usenet threads about the topic:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/latexusersgroup/Dyz3Vyk7ZVk
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4659
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=787

In my experience this kind of documents is done by people which hardly use LaTeX. Even so it is normally done by a group of people which collaborate on it and as long not everyone is using LaTeX this doesn't work easily. I know it from my patent submissions where it is a little similar.

Even if someone would have written a good business plan with LaTeX it is a lot of work to turn it into a good, general template, which people which just finished a business plan usually don't have. I would recommend you to search for general guidelines about how a business plan should look like and then ask specific questions here if you have trouble getting one of the guidelines implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [one-page business plan template](http://100startup.com/resources/business-plan.pdf) inspired by [Chris Guillebeau](https://chrisguillebeau.com/)'s book *[The $100 Startup](http://100startup.com/)*.

CODE:

```
% inspired by: http://100startup.com/resources/business-plan.pdf
%pdfLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl} % KOMA-Script with 12 pt font

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % to change header/footer
    \chead{\large\textbf{The One-Page Business Plan (from The \$100 Startup)}} % centered header
    \cfoot{} % eliminate centered footer page number

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % switch document font to sans serif

\usepackage{paracol} % for two columns and column switching
\usepackage{xcolor} % for using \colorbox
    \newcommand{\firstbox}{\colorbox{lightgray}{\rlap{1.}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}} % new command for 1. gray box
    \newcommand{\secondbox}{\colorbox{lightgray}{\rlap{2.}\hspace{\linewidth}\hspace{-2\fboxsep}}} % new command for 2. gray box

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % no indents for whole document
\maxdeadcycles=200 % prevent issue with 100 dead cycles

\begin{document}

    Answer each question with one or two short sentences.
    \vspace{1cm}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\textcolor{red}{OVERVIEW} \\
\small What will you sell? \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\smallskip

\small Who will buy it? \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\smallskip

\small How will your business idea help people? \normalsize \\\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\smallskip

\textcolor{red}{KA-CHING} \\
\small What will you charge? \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\smallskip

\small How will you get paid? \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\smallskip

\small How else will you make money from this project? \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\

\switchcolumn

\textcolor{red}{HUSTLING} \\
\small How will customers learn about your business? \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\smallskip

\small How can you encourage referrals? \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\smallskip

\textcolor{red}{SUCCESS} \\
\small The project will be successful when it achieves these metrics: \\

\small Number of customers \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\

\small\textit{or} \\

\small Annual net income \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\small\textit{(or other metric)} \\ \normalsize
\smallskip

\textcolor{red}{OBSTACLES/CHALLENGES/QUESTIONS} \\
\small Specific concern of question \#1 \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\
\smallskip

\small Proposed solution to concern \#1 \normalsize \\
\firstbox \\
\secondbox \\

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be one here -> https://github.com/ozkolonur/Latex-based-business-plan-template

Haven't tried it though.

Comment: A possibly useful starting point, but unfortunately, there are many errors and it does not compile.